# Probability and statistical analysis

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability of a missile hitting the target successfully in a trial is 0.2. Five successful hitting are needed to destroy a particular target. What is the probability that the target will be destroyed in the 7th trial?

Comment: Does this mean exactly that the 7th missile destroys it, or that it could already be destroyed by missile 5 or 6?

Comment: My comment [on your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/193073/6179) fully applies.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the probability of exactly $4$ "successes" in the first $6$ trials, and then a success on the $7$th trial. The probability is
$$\binom{6}{4}(0.2)^4(0.8)^2(0.2).$$

The part before the final $0.2$ is a straight Binomial Distribution calculation.

I prefer problems about picking jelly beans from a large jar.